# NSSet useless after count?

Tags: ios, crash, count, exc-bad-access, nsset

Why can't I do

```
NSLog(@"mySet count: %@", [mySet count]);
```

and use the NSSet afterwards? (if I do use it the app crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

I've tried mutable/immutable, retained, copied, autoreleased... all kinds of sets, And after the count message they all become useless and crash. And if I don't count they behave as expected, And if I print them out like this:

```
NSLog(@"mySet: %@", mySet);
```

it's fine! the problem seems to be just with count.

can someone explain me this? I've searched and found nothing regarding this strange behaviour

Comment: the problem was right there, and Dietrich Epp saw it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this crashes is because `[mySet count]` returns an integer, and the `%@` format specifier expects an object.   Change it to:

```
NSLog(@"mySet count: %lu", [mySet count]);
```

This is one of the "gotchas" of Objective C (unless you are already familiar with C or C++): sometimes your data is an object and sometimes your data is not an object.  This is necessary for compatibility with C code.

Comment: ahaha how dumb, missed that completely! i'm glad I've copied pasted or else i could have written the right way (I usually do know that count doens't return an object haha)